# Android focusable and focusable in touch mode

Tags: android, android-layout

I have nested edit texts within table layout and then table layout within scroll view, the focusable / focusable in touch mode doesn't work in real devices but surprisingly it works in emulator.

please can some on offer alternative solution?

Comment: what do you want focusable/focusable in touch mode to do exactly ??

Comment: i have 12 edit texts sitting in table layout and table layout sitting in scroll view, now every time it loads up activity it brings focus to  keypad and keypad is focus on 10 edit text random order. so i want to get rid of keypad coming up every time onCreate is called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Achieved the desired result [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) and added in manifest for each activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```