# Recycler view inside NestedScrollView causes scroll to start in the middle

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I am getting a weird scrolling behavior when I add a RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView.

What happens is that whenever the scrollview has more rows than can be shown in the screen, as soon as the activity is launched, the NestedScrollView starts with an offset from the top (image 1). If there are few items in the scroll view so that they can all be shown at once, this doesn't happen (image 2).

I am using version 23.2.0 of the support library.

**Image 1**: WRONG - starts with offset from the top

[image: Image 1]

**Image 2**: CORRECT - few items in the recycler view

[image: Image 2]

I am pasting below my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Title:"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="@dimen/bodyPadding"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                    android:text="Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Subtitle:"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                    android:padding="@dimen/bodyPadding"
                    android:text="Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."/>

            </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Am I missing something? Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

**Update 1**

It works correctly if I place the following code when initializing my Activity:

```
sv.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sv.scrollTo(0,0);
        }
});
```

Where sv is a reference to the NestedScrollView, however it looks like quite a hack.

**Update 2**

As requested, here is my adapter code:

```
public abstract class ArrayAdapter<T, VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {

    private List<T> mObjects;

    public ArrayAdapter(final List<T> objects) {
        mObjects = objects;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified object at the end of the array.
     *
     * @param object The object to add at the end of the array.
     */
    public void add(final T object) {
        mObjects.add(object);
        notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() - 1);
    }

    /**
     * Remove all elements from the list.
     */
    public void clear() {
        final int size = getItemCount();
        mObjects.clear();
        notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mObjects.size();
    }

    public T getItem(final int position) {
        return mObjects.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(final int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the position of the specified item in the array.
     *
     * @param item The item to retrieve the position of.
     * @return The position of the specified item.
     */
    public int getPosition(final T item) {
        return mObjects.indexOf(item);
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the specified object at the specified index in the array.
     *
     * @param object The object to insert into the array.
     * @param index  The index at which the object must be inserted.
     */
    public void insert(final T object, int index) {
        mObjects.add(index, object);
        notifyItemInserted(index);

    }

    /**
     * Removes the specified object from the array.
     *
     * @param object The object to remove.
     */
    public void remove(T object) {
        final int position = getPosition(object);
        mObjects.remove(object);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    /**
     * Sorts the content of this adapter using the specified comparator.
     *
     * @param comparator The comparator used to sort the objects contained in this adapter.
     */
    public void sort(Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        Collections.sort(mObjects, comparator);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, getItemCount());
    }
}
```

And here is my ViewHolder:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView txt;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txt = (TextView) itemView;
    }

    public void render(String text) {
        txt.setText(text);
    }
}
```

And here is the layout of each item in the RecyclerView (it's just `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` - this screen is only for showing an example of this bug):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

Comment: tried with `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` for `RecyclerView`? smth clearly is "forcing your layout to go to bottom... (where it start when you have 1295 items? bottom or just small top offset like first screen)

Comment: Set android:clipToPadding=“true” to your NestedScrollView .

Comment: also: keeping scrollable view inside another same-way-scrollable view isn't very good pattern... hope you are using proper `LayoutManager`

Comment: Tried both of your suggestions and unfortunately neither worked. @snachmsm no matter the number of items in the recycler view, the offset is always the same. As to whether placing a RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView is a good pattern, this has actually been recommended by a Google engineer at https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/9kZ3SsXdT2T

Comment: I am able to fix it by calling the NestedScrollView's post method, I added it to my question. But it feels like a nasty hack...

Comment: It is a bit hacky, maybe show us pieco of code from adapter and recycler child layout. Also  `LayoutManager` used for `RecyclerView` might be helpful... (I was using same snippet other day, but found focus in child ;) )

Comment: @snachmsm I added the code to my question, maybe it will help but I wonder if this is an internal bug in the implementation of NestedScrollView...

Comment: `mObjects.add(object);
        notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() - 1);` getItemCount should be get before add, notify only new ;) maybe this whole list redrawing (which is unnessesary, only new item should be drawn) causes this offset and scroll a bit. still: `LayoutManager` is also important if custom

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Thanks for the post runnable hack. I have my layout in fragment, that is in Drawer layout. It sets the offset on every drawer close as well :-/

Comment: Even i have same issue when using RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView. It is a bad pattern because the recycler pattern itself won't work. All the views will be drawn at a time (since WRAP_CONTENT needs height of recycler view). There won't be any view recycling in the background, so the main purpose of recycler view itself is not working. But it is easy to manage data and draw layout by using recycler view, that's the only reason you can use this pattern. So better not to use it until unless you require it for sure.

Comment: I have an issue, where the RecycleView is inside a NestedScrollview. I can't use recycleview.scrollToPosition(X); , it just doesn't work. I tried everything in the last 6 days, but I can get over it. any suggestion? I would be very thankful !

Comment: I have the same issue. We are trapped at work into using RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView. I'd just like to highlight to everyone that this completely destroys all recycling ability. All your views for the whole list will be laid out on first visiting the screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove focus from RecyclerView inside ScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850550/how-to-remove-focus-from-recyclerview-inside-scrollview)

Answer (score 262, accepted):

I solved such issue by setting:

```
<ImageView ...
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
```

to my view above RecyclerView (which was hidden after unwanted scroll). Try to set this property to your LinearLayout above RecyclerView or to LinearLayout which is container of RecyclerView (helped me in another case).

As I see in NestedScrollView source it tries to focus the first possible child in onRequestFocusInDescendants and if only RecyclerView is focusable it wins.

Edit (thanks to Waran): and for smooth scroll don't forget to set `yourRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`

Comment: By the way, you need to add     yourRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); in order to make scroll smooth

Comment: Works perfectly, but you have to make sure to add the above attribute to views that are not seen after the scroll.

Comment: pardon me, where I should add this attribute? to all of my views except Recycle View ??

Comment: @Kenji only to first view inside of LinearLayout where RecyclerView is placed. Or to that LinearLayout (RecyclerView container) itself if first change doesn't help.

Comment: @DmitryGavrilko I have an issue, where the RecycleView is inside a NestedScrollview. I can't use recycleview.scrollToPosition(X); , it just doesn't work. I tried everything in the last 6 days, but I can get over it. any suggestion? I would be very thankful !

Comment: You can also just set `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`to the recyclerView so that you dont need to set true for all the other views.

Comment: Agree with @Aksiom. Setting recyclerView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false) worked well for me.

Comment: Agree with Dmitry Gavrilko, worked after setting android:focusableInTouchMode="true" to the linearlayout which contains recyclerview. @Aksiom setting android:focusableInTouchMode="false" to the recyclerView doesn't worked for me.

Answer (score 113):

In your `LinearLayout` immediate after `NestedScrollView`, use `android:descendantFocusability` in the following way

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
```

**EDIT**

Since many of them getting this answer useful,  will also provide explanation.

The use of `descendantFocusability` is given [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#descendantFocusability). And as of `focusableInTouchMode` over [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#focusableInTouchMode).
So using `blocksDescendants` in `descendantFocusability` do not allows it's child to gain focus while touching and hence unplanned behaviour can be stopped.

As for `focusInTouchMode`, both `AbsListView` and `RecyclerView` calls the method `setFocusableInTouchMode(true);` in their constructor by default, so it is not required to use that attribute in your XML layouts.

And for `NestedScrollView` following method is used:

```
private void initScrollView() {
        mScroller = ScrollerCompat.create(getContext(), null);
        setFocusable(true);
        setDescendantFocusability(FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        final ViewConfiguration configuration = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext());
        mTouchSlop = configuration.getScaledTouchSlop();
        mMinimumVelocity = configuration.getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity();
        mMaximumVelocity = configuration.getScaledMaximumFlingVelocity();
    }
```

Here, `setFocusable()` method is used instead of `setFocusableInTouchMode()`. But according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24156248/842607), `focusableInTouchMode` should be avoided unless for certain conditions as it breaks consistency with Android normal behaviour. A game is a good example of an application that can make good use of the focusable in touch mode property. MapView, if used in fullscreen as in Google Maps, is another good example of where you can use focusable in touch mode correctly.

Comment: Thank you! It works in my case. Unfortunately android:focusableInTouchMode="true" not worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me. I added this line of code to the parent view of my recyclerview (in my case, it was a LinearLayout) and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I was using NestedScrollView followed by LinearLayout which contains RecyclerView and EditText. The scrolling behavior was fixed by using android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" inside LinearLayout but EditText cannot gain focus. Any idea what is happening?

Comment: @SagarChapagain It's the property of `blocksDescendants` to block all descendant's focus. I am not sure, but try `beforeDescendants`

Comment: @JimitPatel my problem was solved using
`recyclerView.setFocusable(false);
nestedScrollView.requestFocus();`

Comment: What if I have touchable views in the recyclerView? The `blocksDescendants` property will avoid any click listeners triggers on them, won't it?

Comment: @LeandroTemperoni Actually, the one who questioned this never had any focus related elements in his code, so this is the solution. While coming to your problem, I think focus for `EditText` is the problem, but for `Button` even I am not aware of it, it should work according to me, because I was using horizontal `RecyclerView` with click on element to next screen. But with latest updates I am not sure. Try it out!! and say whether working or not. :)

Comment: I was experiencing something similar in a layout with an `AppBarLayout` + `CollapsingToolbarLayout` + `NestedScrollView` + `RecyclerView`.  Adding `android:clipToPadding="true"`  to the `NestedScrollView` and the `RecyclerView`, plus `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the child viewgroup of the `NestedScrollView` and `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` to the `RecyclerView` fixed all the issues.

Answer (score 20):

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

inside LinearLayout Worked for me .

Comment: But does it mean that focus on the views inside will be blocked, and users won't be able to reach them?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue and sovled by extending NestedScrollView and disabling focusing children. For some reason, RecyclerView always requested focus even when I just opened and closed the drawer.

```
public class DummyNestedScrollView extends NestedScrollView {
public DummyNestedScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public DummyNestedScrollView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public DummyNestedScrollView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

/**
 * Fixind problem with recyclerView in nested scrollview requesting focus
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314836/recycler-view-inside-nestedscrollview-causes-scroll-to-start-in-the-middle
 * @param child
 * @param focused
 */
@Override
public void requestChildFocus(View child, View focused) {
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Request focus");
    //super.requestChildFocus(child, focused);

}


/**
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314836/recycler-view-inside-nestedscrollview-causes-scroll-to-start-in-the-middle
 * @param direction
 * @param previouslyFocusedRect
 * @return
 */
@Override
protected boolean onRequestFocusInDescendants(int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Request focus descendants");
    //return super.onRequestFocusInDescendants(direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: It works but it also breaks focus concept and you can easy get situation with two focused fields on the screen. So use it only if you have no EditText inside `RecyclerView` holders.

Answer (score 5):

In my case this code solves mine issue

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
NestedScrollView nestedScrollView= findViewById(R.id.nestedScrollView);

recyclerView.setFocusable(false);
nestedScrollView.requestFocus();

//populate recyclerview here
```

My layout contains a parent layout as NestedScrollView which has a child LinearLayout. The LinearLayout has orientation "vertical" and childs RecyclerView and EditText. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584187/nestedscrollview-wont-start-from-top)

Answer (score 5):

Just add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on the ViewGroup inside the NestedScrollView.

Answer (score 2):

I have two guesses.

First:Try putting this line on your NestedScrollView

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Second:
Use

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
```

as your parent view
Like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="vertical"
                      android:padding="16dp">

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title:"/>

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/bodyPadding"
                android:text="Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum"/>

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Subtitle:"/>

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/bodyPadding"
                android:text="Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

My last possible solution. I swear :)

Comment: And adding the CoordinatorLayout as the parent view didn't work either... Thanks anyways

Answer (score 2):

**This problem arrives due to recycle view Focus.**

Automatically all focus gone to recycle view if its size extended the size of screen.

adding `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to first ChildView like `TextView`, `Button` and so on(Not on `ViewGroup` like `Linear`, `Relative` and So on) make sense to solve the problem but API Level 25 and above solution doesn't work.

Just add these 2 line in your ChildView like `TextView`, `Button` and So on (Not on `ViewGroup` like `Linear`, `Relative` and So on)

```
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
 android:focusable="true"
```

I just faced this problem on API level 25. I hope other people don't waste time in this.

**For Smooth Scrolling On RecycleView add this line**

```
 android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

but adding this attiributes only works with API level 21 or above. If you want that smoothing scrolling work on below API level 25 then add this line in your class

```
 mList = findViewById(R.id.recycle_list);
 ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(mList, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java code, after initializing your recyclerView and setting the adapter, add this line:

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)
```

You can also try to wrap the layout withing a relativeLayout so that the views stay at the same position but recyclerView (which scroll) is first in xml hierarchy. The last suggestion a desperate attempt:p

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

because the ViewGroup will block its descendants from receiving focus. This is an accessibility issue.

If you want to avoid the `nestedscrollview` to receive focus, you can add a dummy layout which is focusable above the `nestedscrollview`.

```
   <View
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:focusable="true"
       android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In My case It was scrolling and focusing to recyclerview due to, I had added  **android:layout_gravity="center"** in parent linearlayout.
After removing it works properly.

Answer (score -1):

As I am late in responding, but may can help someone else.
Just use the below or higher version in your app level build.gradle and the issue is removed.

```
compile com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1
```

Answer (score -1):

to scroll to the top, just call this in `setcontentview`:

```
scrollView.SmoothScrollTo(0, 0);
```

Comment: this does not provide answer to the question