# How to remove focus from RecyclerView inside ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I have a Scrollview which contains an ImageView and RecyclerView.
if navigation drawer opened then closed the RecyclerView auto scrolling to top, How to stop this?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewMain"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/imageView_main_icons_line"
           android:src="@drawable/main_line" />

              ...


       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_activity_main_passenger_log"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Having a RecyclerView into a ScrollView is not a good idea at all. You can easily get into a trouble with the click / swipe events by using such structure. My advice - change your design

Comment: @TodorKostov I can't , except this issue every thing is ok, the recyclerView's height is wrap_content so it is ok to put recyclerview in scrollview

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This problem because of recyclerView has default focus.

> Solution

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Add         `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to your immediate layout of scrollView

Comment: Added android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to RecyclerView's parent, which is LinearLayout, and it worked.

Comment: Please make sure to see landerlyoung's answer below. Following this accepted answer can lead to many problems for users utilizing physical keyboards. Every Android app is usable with a hard keyboard by default, unless you blindly follow Rahul Devanavar's answer.

Comment: Didn't help. I have relative layout wrapped around recyclerview.

Comment: Quite useful when if you are doing anything at view holder with handler to update the content periodically. Thanks @Rahul

Answer (score 30):

That is because RecyclerView ALWAYS set:

```
setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

this is hard coded in its constructor.

so if you apply those attribute in your XML for a RecyclerView

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focudeableInTouchMode="false"
```

that would be useless, you end up with recycleView.isFocusable() == true...

so the most elegant solution is to disable foucusable for RecyclerView's Parent.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    ...
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        ...
    />
/>
```

or you can just simply setFocusable(false)

Comment: it work but it'll endedup blocking any child inside of scrollview/nestedscrollview

Answer (score 3):

Check out **clearFocus()** from here [Android Dev Doc.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

You can set a **DrawerListener** to your navigation drawer and use the **onDrawerStateChanged()** or some of the other options from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html) to call **clearFocus()** on your **RecyclerView**.

Comment: thanks, I have added the drawerListener but I can't remove focus on recyclerView,any idea?

Comment: @Delta7 Now that's strange... add **android:focusable="true"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"**  to your recyclerView and try again

Comment: it is focusing instead of removing focus :/

Comment: and scrolling to top

Comment: @Delta7 discard my last comment... ok on **onDrawerStateChanged()** set **recyclerView.setFocusable(false)** that's not the best way, but it sould work, if not... sadly I don't know how to help :/

Answer (score 3):

Adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` can restrict scroll to recylerview but if you have edittext inside your layout, this property can block the focus of that particular edittext too. So if you are using this property please make sure you are removing this property in your kotlin/java class once the layout loaded.

`parentLayout?.descendantFocusability = FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS
(view as ViewGroup).descendantFocusability = FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS`

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following code in your linear layout, works 100% `            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```