# Keyboard input method changes when scroll recycler view

Tags: android, input, scroll, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

I have ExpandableRecyclerView with EditTexts. On EditText I set input method number. And when I click on the EditText, everything is okay. But when I scroll my RecyclerView keyboard changes to standard. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: may be keyboard opens from the other view that contains normal keyboard

Comment: If you can post your sample code here. it'll be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the perfect solution, but here are a few steps to achieve this:

- Prevent your `RecyclerView` from receiving focus. I had to do this from code for the reasons explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42688298/1620248). This will hide your keyboard once you scroll your `RecyclerView` and your `EditText` gets out of view instead of changing it to standard
- Then use a [listener to detect when the keyboard is open/closed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25681196/1620248) and when it gets opened use the lines below to prevent the keyboard from closing until the user specifically does so:

  ```
  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0)
  imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0)
  ```