# Multiple horizontal RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView steal focus

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tv

Actually I'm currently working for a AndroidTV app. I have multiple horizontal `RecyclerView` right to left inside a `NestedScrollView` like that image.

Problem is that when I scroll more towards left, then focus moves to different list or different view which is not good.

I don't want the focus to change. If the list reaches to the end, then focus should remain at same position.

**I tried :**

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" //in parent layout
```

**But it didn't work..**

**Can anyone help me out ??**

[image]

**Not solved**

Comment: Try following the solution in this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42688298/5995040)

Comment: Already tried but not helpful @Mr.Rebot

Comment: I solved my problem with using android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" for root layout in the scrollview. Also using nestedscrollview instead of scrollview.

Comment: i also tried that android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" in my root layout in the ScrollView but after it use focus not detect in RecyclerView's child. @asozcan

Comment: just wondering, have you solved this problem? I'm facing same issue right now

Comment: Not at all but we can say 80% solved..Flow the steps..

  1.Take ScrollView as a root

  2. Use in that root  

    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

  3. At child layout's root element use

    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"

Follow those steps and let me know... @Kyk

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `ScrollView` to `NestedScrollView`. A reason behind this is

```
**NestedScrollView**
```

> NestedScrollView is just like ScrollView, but it supports acting as
>   both a nested scrolling parent and child on both new and old versions
>   of Android. Nested scrolling is enabled by default.

```
**ScrollView**
```

> Layout container for a view hierarchy that can be scrolled by the
>   user, allowing it to be larger than the physical display. A ScrollView
>   is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing
>   the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout
>   manager with a complex hierarchy of objects

This will help you to determine which layout is being focused.

Comment: Already I used NestedScrollView but not helpful... @Dipali shah

Comment: In question you have mentioned your `Recyclerview` is inside `ScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below structure for nested scroll

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_search_all"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:isScrollContainer="false"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:isScrollContainer="false"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

I hope this will help!

Comment: Sorry, its not change anything. Thanku for your help..  @Alpesh Sorathiya

Answer (score 0):

Try using this one code in your recycleview section 2:

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```