# Android - Recycler view resizes when app is on background

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have this very weird bug on my app. Every time I open my app my view works perfectly, but when I try to put my app in background and open my app again, my recycler view resizes.

Here's an image to describe it properly:

**This is the correct image:**

[image]

**This is the image that messes up my recyclerview when the app is on background, then I open it again.**

[image]

**There are also times that all images in my recyclerview are gone. Here's a screenshot:**

[image]

This is my `onResume()` code:

```
public void onResume()
 {
   Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
   if (fragment instanceof MenuFragment)
   {
     FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     transaction.remove(fragment);
     transaction.commit();
     transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
     transaction.addToBackStack(null);
     transaction.commit();

   }
 }
```

This is my view pager layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/app_background">
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/action_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/nav_bar"
            layout="@layout/home_screen_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.yotadevices.widget.RtlViewPager
        android:id="@+id/menuFragment_viewPager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttons"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nav_bar"/>
    <include
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        layout="@layout/navigation_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/menuFragment_viewPager" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's my list layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

What do you think is the problem here?

**PS: The bug occurs only on selected phones. Not all. We've tested this on Samsung Galaxy s8+ and it works well.**

Comment: Can you send us you onResume code? Thanks.

Comment: @JAArce i've added my `onResume` code as well as my layout.

Comment: Why did you set height width to 0dp to `RecyclerView` ? @PinoyStackOverflower

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto because I am using constraintLayouts, I've anchored the RecyclerView to the parent and height and width to 0 will match the constraints. Let me know if I am doing this wrong, i'm glad to take your opinion. Thanks.

Comment: @PinoyStackOverflower Try putting match_parent instead.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto - still doesn't work.

Comment: Can wee see this class please `com.yotadevices.widget.RtlViewPager`?

Comment: Hello @cutiko - Here is the class - https://github.com/yotadevices/RtlViewPager Hope this helps!

Comment: Is it the same case with this issue; [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314836/recycler-view-inside-nestedscrollview-causes-scroll-to-start-in-the-middle/41670704](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314836/recycler-view-inside-nestedscrollview-causes-scroll-to-start-in-the-middle/41670704)

Comment: @yunard - I don't think so. It's different.

Comment: @PinoyStackOverflower: Have you tried replacing the `RecyclerView` with normal `view`, just to check if the same issue persists?

Comment: what is the purpose of your `onResume` code?

Comment: I'll re-ask what @KarandeepAtwal asked. What's the purpose of that `onResume` code? From my (8 years) experience I can't see a any. You only make transactions on first init (during onCreate and the savedInstances is null) and when you need to change the layout.

Comment: if item decoration is added in recyclerview may be this issue is occurring.

Comment: Well this seems quite a bug . Does your `Activity` any `configChanges` attributes in manifest ? Try to add `android:configChanges="screenSize|keyboard|orientation|screenLayout"` .

Comment: I have confused. In List Layout recycler view size is 0 dp, and it is wrapped by ConstraintLayout matchparent and you included one more time in ConstraintLayout with wrap content in Main view xml why is it like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem by breaking part the included layouts. So instead of adding an included layout, I just transferred all the included in to the main XML layout.

Even though this fixed the problem, i still do not know why the bug occurred in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using only single child view, it's better to use `FrameLayout`. Then in `RecyclerView` use match_parent parameters in layout attribute, so your code should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

By the way my best method to debug scenarios like this is to write `android:background="#0000FF"` in every view, to see how it inflates.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on how to debug, but I already did that. I also did using FrameLayout, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Does it allow to scroll at least a bit inside recyclerview?

Comment: Yes it does scroll. If the view is still visible, it can be scrolled. Hope this helps.

Comment: `ScrollView` probably messes up with `RecyclerView` try to get `RecyclerView` items height sum and then set it to `RecyclerView`, you can find how its done in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28498247/9389798

Comment: Is a ViewPager considered a ScrollView? If that is not the case, then I don't have a RecyclerView inside a ScrollView.

Comment: `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_menu_hScrollView"` Have you tried changing this constraint inside `ViewPager` to parrent?

Comment: Sorry, I think you thought I have a RecyclerView inside the HorizontalScrollView. That is not the case. I have edited my question and information for clarity.

Comment: Oh sorry I mistaken. Have you tried detaching and then attaching fragment instead of replacing it? Like so: `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();`

Comment: Actually, I already did that. We just replaced that with `replaced()`. You can check that on my `onResume()` code.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to first remove the old fragment if you are going to call `replace(R.id.container_id, newFragment);`
- You don't need to call commit after every change (`remove()`, `replace()`, etc.), call all your changes then end it with a `commit()`
- If your activity did not lose/change its state (e.g. rotate), then you are just removing and adding the same fragment for no reason
- You are checking if it is a `MenuFragment` in the `if` statement, then, oddly enough, if the condition holds, you go and re-add the `MenuFragment`, when you should probably replace it if it's not a `MenuFragment`

  ```
  if (!(fragment instanceof MenuFragment)) {
      FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      Fragment menuFragment = new MenuFragment();
      // pass any data...
      transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, menuFragment);
      transaction.addToBackStack(null);
      transaction.commit();
  }
  ```

Adding `Log.d(TAG, "method name")` in your `onResume()`, `onPause()` might help you know what's happening.

Also, checking the view hierarchy in `Tools > Layout Inspector` might also help.

Enabling `Settings > Developer Options > Show Layout Bounds` on your emulator might also help.

Let me know if I had anything wrong. Also let me know if any of this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

To start off, declare your layouts in a more specific way rather than using root elements that are certainly not used.

Here's the list layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Second, the onPause is mainly responsible for saving the app state automatically if you don't have much to implement. It is best to remove the onResume and let it take care of itself.

Answer (score 0):

keep width of `recyclerview` as `match_parent` and height as `wrap_content`,
after that ,for your item layout,put height and width as a fixed value,such as `50dp` or `70dp`, which can keep the item's height and width same in any mode u want.
i hope this helps,if this answer is not helpful,please ignore this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a subclass of android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter to load Fragments rather then putting code in on resume.

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private static final int ITEMS = 4;

    PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                return Fragment1.newInstance();
            case 1:
                return Fragment2.newInstance();
            case 2:
                return Fragment3.newInstance();
            case 3:
                return Fragment4.newInstance();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ITEMS;
    }

}
```

The new instance method of each fragment must be:

```
public static Fragment1 newInstance() {
    return new Fragment1 ();
}
```

In your activity write following in onCreate method:

```
PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
//rtlViewPager -- object of RtlViewPager
rtlViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
rtlViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
```