# Wrong Accessibility Traversal order in Nested Recyclerview inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, talkback, accessibility

For accessibility I'm trying to traverse through a (nested) `RecyclerView`, using Talkback.
However, instead of scrolling all the way to the bottom of the screen (vertically), the swipe of the horizontal `RecyclerView` is triggered. As a result, it is not possible to traverse all the way to the bottom.

The view looks like this:

```
<SwipeRefreshLayout>
  <...>
  <NestedScrollView>
    <RecyclerView orientation=horizontal>
       
       <!-- This is for every view of the horizontal RecyclerView --> 
       <CardView> 
         <RecyclerView orientation=vertical>
         </RecyclerView>
       </CardView>
       <!-- Till here -->
    
    </RecyclerView>
  </NestedScrollView>
</SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

More detailed explanation of the problem:

- Start with Talkback on and the first view is selected.
- The horizontal `RecyclerView` contains multiple items which are loaded in the background.
- The vertical `RecyclerView` contains items that exceed the screen when it is first loaded. So lets say you see 10 items, but there are 20 in the vertical list.
- You start swiping through the items with Talkback and are almost at the 10th item of the vertical `RecyclerView`.
- So you swipe once more and you are on the 10th item, which is the last view that is currently visible.
- The next swipe will result in going to the next view of the **horizontal** `RecyclerView`. However, it should continue scrolling to the next view in the *vertical* `RecyclerView`....

How I understand it, is that going to the next view of the **horizontal** `RecyclerView` can be done by using to fingers as real swipe of the app. The two finger swipe is explained [here](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6151827?hl=en&ref_topic=3529932).

What I tried:

- Use the `android:focusableInTouchMode` and `android:descendantFocusability` to improve the traversal order, as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61590920/talkback-focus-goes-to-toolbar-items-when-recyclerview-within-nestedscrollview-i).
- Set the `android:importantForAccessbility` to `false` on the horizontal `RecyclerView` items that are not visible at that moment. Note that it is hard to decide whether this was sufficient because the views are rather complex.
- Play with `accessibilityTraversalAfter` en `accessibilityTraversalBefore` to improve the traversal order.

The question is, how can I make ensure that Talkback traverses to the end of the screen? In other words; that traversing with Talkback does not trigger going to the next item in the *horizontal* recycler?

Comment: It seems to be hard to do it correctly, so many questions without answers

Comment: @476rick Did you solve this issue already? I am working on the same problem.